# How to get rid of drain flies?

Tags: drains

I am having trouble with drain flies in my kitchen and bathrooms. One of our bedrooms also has them and there are no drains in that room. The room is a built on from an old porch. How do I remove drain flies from the drainpipes and the buildup?

Comment: Bleach, DDT, flame thrower, legal insecticides.  You need to find where they are coming from first.  Just because they are called drain flies, does not mean that is the only source, just where they are found most.  Fruit flies are found around fruit, but do not come from fruit(hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Though they're found around drains, [any standing water can attract them](https://www.countryliving.com/home-maintenance/cleaning/a29364962/how-to-get-rid-of-drain-flies/) (and also attract mosquitoes, which are disease carriers).

- Get rid of standing water.

  - Since the bedroom was built from a porch, look for water underneath, and *provide a way for it to drain*, such as a [French drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_drain). This will also reduce the likelihood of the wood underneath rotting out.
  - In bathroom and kitchen, keep the drain plugged, or use a fine mesh sink strainer, such as [these examples](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=fine%20sink%20drain%20strainer&crid=L866LH66XVRN&sprefix=fine%20sink%2Caps%2C306). There are overflow openings on sinks and tubs, but those should not be blocked, because they also provides a path for air to escape.
- Once a weak, pour boiling water down all drains (use the water from boiling foods, to save energy), *except* toilets: there are wax rings at their base, and hot water might melt them.
- You can also sprinkle baking soda in hidden areas, such as the crawl space under the bedroom.
- You can also make a trap, e.g., a plastic box with some cider vinegar, with small holes in the lid. The flies will find their way in, but not out.